# Is there a function that integrates to the same constant, regardless of the interval of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking for a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ so that for $c\in\mathbb R$ given,

$$\int_x^y f(x,s)ds=c$$
for all $x<y$.

I suspect that it is not possible, since differentiating with respect to $y$ yields $f(x,y)=0$. But I am hoping to be proven wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your integrals exist, then the limit of $\int_x^y f(x,s)\; ds$ as $y \to x+$ must be $0$.

Comment: You could try $f(x,s) = 2 c \delta(s-x)$, but the Dirac delta is a distribution not a **function**.